# Call back JS code

Tags: javascript, callback

In other languages I was used to instructions being executed in order like 1,2,3. JS doesn't work that way. I need very simple JS code  to insure that instructions are executed 1,2,3 and not 2,1,3 one time and 3,1,2 the next.

Comment: Step 1: show your code. Step 2: explain the problem with said code.

Comment: This might interest you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop .

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  We'd love to help you, but you might have better luck after reading the help center articles such as [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  But glad to have you here, Dad. :)

Answer (score 3):

> In other languages I was used to instructions being executed in order like 1,2,3. JS doesn't work that way.

Actually, JavaScript works **exactly** that way.

Sounds like you're calling a function with a callback to do something asynchronously.  Let's try an example.

```
console.log('1');
doSomethingLater(function callback () {
  // This is my callback code
  console.log('3');
});
console.log('2');
```

The output will be 1, 2, 3.

What you're doing when calling `doSomethingLater` is passing a reference to an anonymous function as a *parameter*.  `doSomethingLater` won't call that function until it's programmed to do, which is usually some time later.

If we ignore the callback, it's very easy to see that things are executed in-order.

```
console.log('1');
doSomethingLater();
console.log('2');
```

These three statements are executed in-order.

To futher illustrate the point, consider an example with `setTimeout()`, where we only execute other code after one second.  (If you're not familiar with `setTimeout()`, go look that up first and then come back here to keep reading.)

```
console.log('1');
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('3');
}, 1000);
console.log('2');
```

In this example, we're not trying to execute the callback until a second after `setTimeout()` is called, so basically one second after `console.log('2')`;

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript ***is*** executed in order.

```js
function doSomething(x) {
    console.log('did something', x);
}

console.log(1);
console.log(2);
console.log(3);

doSomething(1);
doSomething(2);
doSomething(3);
```

Comment: I apologize. The specific issue is that data returned from function1 needs to be available for function2. The functions execute in order - START in order, but do not finish in order. Function2 cannot start until function1 is finished. It must wait until function1 is finished. That's where the callback comes in.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson - you might consider looking into [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).